# JQUERY función .each()

Tags: jquery

Tengo que cambiar el fondo azul de un input text solo si este contiene un valor numérico, si no es así,  ponerlo de color rosa, tengo que usar 
a fuerzas el método **.each()**

**Index.html:**

```
<div id=“proyecto”>
                    <input type="text" value=“hola”/>
                    <input type="text" value=“0987”/>
                    <input type="button" onclick="tarea1()"/>
</div>
```

**Jquery:**

```
function tarea1(){
 $(‘#proyecto’).each(function(indice){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se me ocurre lo siguiente, agregar la clase "captura" a tus input de tipo texto, para hacer la busqueda por esta clase, luego  validar por cada uno "each" si es un numero y asignes el color correspondiente.

Se agrego la validación en el caso de que el valor del input se deje en blanco.

```js
function tarea1(){
 $('.captura').each(function(){
      
      if(isNaN(this.value) || this.value.trim()=='')//funcion para validar si es un numero
        $(this).css("background-color","pink");
      else
        $(this).css("background-color","#13C7FE");
    })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="proyecto">
                    <input type="text" class="captura" value="hola"/>
                    <input type="text" class="captura" value="0987"/>
                    <input type="button" value="Aceptar" onclick="tarea1()"/>
</div>
```

espero te sirva, saludos.

Comment: Hacen falta más validaciones quizá. Por ejemplo, si se deja en blanco lo asume como si hubiera un número y lo pone en azul. ¿Es ese el comportamiento deseado?

Comment: es correcta la observación, para esa validación hace falta incluir que no se permita dejar el input vacio o que se valide el vacio como texto. Editare y agregare dicha validación, Gracias.

Comment: Está mejor ahora, pero, ¿por qué mejor en vez de hacer esto ` if(isNaN(this.value) || this.value.trim()=='')` no limpias con `trim()` y guardas el dato en una variable y la usas para comparar? A mi me gusta molestar al código, poniendolo en situaciones difíciles. Por ejemplo si yo escribo `[espacio] 2`, tu código me lo asume como un número, pero en realidad es una cadena compuesta por un espacio y el número dos.

Answer (score 2):

**Tengo la respuesta para este codigo:**

Su explicacion es la siguiente:

1) Se ha separado el **input** que sirve de boton para ejecutar la funcion tarea1() del bloque **DIV** por razones de organizacion.

2) El recorrido se hace por medio de contar los elementos que existe en la pagina que contentan con el atributo y tipo especifico:

```
$('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
```

3) Se toma el valor de cada etiqueta recorrida con:

```
var valor = $(this).val();
```

4) La siguente condicion if() tiene un comando Jquery que evalua el contenido, si es numerico el resultado es TRUE de lo contrario sale FALSE

```
if ($.isNumeric(valor)) {
```

5) Se asigna un color azul de fondo para la **etiqueta input** que tenga el valor numerico. (solo numerico)

```
$(this).css("background-color", "blue");
```

6) Se asigna un color rosa para la etiqueta input que tenga un valor diferente al numerio / alfabetico (si es alfanumerico tambien es considerado)

```
$(this).css("background-color", "pink");
```

7) muesta el numero de item leido

```
console.log(e);
```

Para su ejemplo ejecutado:

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        input {
            display: flex;
            margin-top: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="proyecto">
        <input type="text" value="hola"/>
        <input type="text" value="0987"/>
    </div>
         <br>
         <input type="button" value="identificar" onclick="tarea1()"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function tarea1(){
        
         $('input[type="text"]').each(function(e){
               var valor = $(this).val();
               if ($.isNumeric(valor)) {
                  $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
               } else {
                $(this).css("background-color", "pink");
               }
               console.log(e);
            });
         
        };

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Espero que sea de ayuda.